# cachemanager.contains vs cachemanager.getdata

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have a situation where I need to check if the data exists in the cache and if exists I need to retrieve it or else add it to the cache.

I have 2 options here. One is I can first call the `CacheManager.Contains(key)` and if it is there then I will call `CacheManager.GetData(key)` or else I can directly call `CacheManeger.GetData(key)` and check it for null value. I am not sure which one is better. In the first approach it seems like a good practise but I am making two calls for same thing. Whereas in second approach I am directly retrieving the data from cache without checking.

The question here is which one is a better practise and which one will give better performance? If you can provide little insight on working of both then it would be really helpful.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This smells of premature optimization. I very much doubt that the performance difference will be of concern.

I'd personally go for the combination first checking `Contains`, then retreiving the value if it's there, because I think that more clearly describes what you are doing (to a human reader maintaining your code).

Comment: I am trying to optimize the code..so this thing just came up in my mind..one thing I have noticed is after calling the .contains method if I call the .getdata it takes 1700ms + 0.2ms and if I call the .getdata directly it takes same time as the .contains method. What could be the reason?

Comment: Well it seems like it's the CacheManager that is doing somthing internally to fetch the data that you asked for. How is the CacheManager storing the data?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference between both cases. But first one consume little bit much time as compare to second one.Second option is much better performance wise that will retrieve data  weather cache has or not. Then check it for Null. That will consume little bit less time.